# Does freezing tights make them more durable?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, polymers, materials, temperature

Various blog posts and articles suggest that freezing a pair of tights will make them last longer.

From a blog named [Eclipsed Moon](http://www.eclipsedmoon.net/how-to-keep-tights-from-ripping/):

> - **Put your tights in the freezer.**
>
>   I thought that this was a silly old-wives tale, but it actually does
>     work! Putting your tights in a plastic bag and storing them in the
>     freezer when you aren’t using them helps keep the material firm and
>     less prone to ripping.

From an [article on *PureWow*](http://www.purewow.com/fashion/How-Freezing-Your-Tights-Will-Change-Your-Whole-Damn-Life):

> Good thing there’s a super-easy trick for extending the life of your
>   tights.
>
> *You freeze them.*
>
> Yes, it sounds crazy, but hear us out: The next time you buy a new
>   pair (and before you wear them), run them under water until they’re
>   damp. Then place them in a plastic bag and freeze overnight. Take them
>   out and give them a day to defrost and thaw out.
>
> You only need to do this once — after that, you’re good to go. The
>   chilly temps firm and strengthen the individual fibers of your tights,
>   making them less susceptible to runs later on.

---

I'm skeptical.  My questions are:

1. Where is the evidence?  Are there any controlled studies confirming this phenomenon?
2. Does the water make any difference?
3. Is this advice for storage, one-time treatment, or both?
4. If it is indeed effective as a one-time treatment, why don't they come pre-treated from the factory?
5. If it works, why does it work?

Comment: Cross-posted here after being [closed on Lifehacks](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/9586/9874), since this seem to be the closest to a Materials Science site.

Comment: Did you actually check it? Chemistry is an experimental science, you know.